# problem VAT for muti views

Tags: magento2, vat, rules

My website run with the version 2.1.2
I created two views. one for switzerland and one other for France.

So, i would like to get two VAT different.
8% for switzerland and 20% for France.

But impossible to Put in place this rules.
However i created my taxe in Stores > Zones and tax rates.
And my rule in System in Stores > Tax rules.

Then, In Stores > Configuration > Sales > Taxes i changed the default country for each views in Estimated default tax.

Nothing there does not work.
Regardless of the view, the rate is maintained at 8%.

I know what to do, I tried everything.Hoping someone would have an idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Sales->VAT->Manage tax rules and Create Rule
[image: vat]

Its works for me..

Comment: yes, i created a rule but i have the problem too.